# Python big_o seems to return completely incorrect results - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, list, time-complexity, big-o, flatten

I am comparing runtimes of different ways of flattening a list of lists using the [*big_o* module](https://pypi.org/project/big-O/), and for following methods my function does not return the expected results, namely:

1. This one:

```
    def itertools_chain_from_iterable(arr): 
        return list(chain.from_iterable(arr))
```

returns "constant", which can't possibly be true.

2. This one:

```
    def merge_extend(self,arr):
        output = []
        for l in arr:
            output.extend(l)
        return output
```

returns "cubic" (shouldn't it be quadratic at most?), while...

3. ..this one

```
    def merge_w_sum(self,arr): 
        return sum(arr,[])
```

returns "linear" (I'm quite sure it should be quadratic, see [proof here](https://mathieularose.com/how-not-to-flatten-a-list-of-lists-in-python#:%7E:text=We%20can%20conclude%20that%20sum(lst%2C%20%5B%5D)%20has%20quadratic%20complexity.%20Comparing%20to%3A).

4. Furthermore, the list comprehension one

```
    def merge_bucket(self,bucket):
        return [number for n in bucket for number in n]
```

returns "polynomial", which seems terrifying (would expect linear here as well)

Code used to calculate the complexities:

```
print('<function name>:', big_o.big_o(<function name>, 
       lambda n:[big_o.datagen.integers(9900,1,9999999) for n in range(50)],
       n_measures=20)[0])
```

Output:

```
complexity of itertools_chain_from_iterable: Constant: time = 0.0013 (sec)
complexity of merge_w_sum: Linear: time = 0.46 + 6.2E-07*n (sec)
complexity of merge_extend: Cubic: time = 0.048 + -2.3E-18*n^3 (sec)
complexity of merge_bucket: Polynomial: time = 0.2 * x^-0.019 (sec)
```

What is it that I'm doing (or understanding) wrong? Many thanks in advance for useful tips!

Comment: What is this big_o?

Comment: If all of those demonstrate the issue, I suggest you demonstrate it using only one of them. And then don't squeeze its code into a hard to read long single line.

Comment: `big_o` is not part of the standard library, and the tag is about the general computer science concept, not any particular third-party library. If you want us to understand what code you're talking about, a link would be useful; but you might start by reading the documentation first. If you have a simple example that gives the wrong result after your best attempt to verify that you are correctly using the library, consider reporting a bug.

Comment: All of those are linear time except for `sum(arr,[])` which is quadratic. We can't answer questions about some library that you don't even direct us towards

Comment: @KellyBundy see [here:] (https://pypi.org/project/big-O/), link was also added to the post
concerning the demonstration of the issue: point taken, edited correspondingly

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 
ad **link**: added to the post

ad **you might start by reading the documentation first**: the documentation is where I learned about this module and how to use (examples, etc) in the first place.


ad **simple example that gives the wrong result after your best attempt to verify that you are correctly using the library** - not sure, this is why I posted the question here

Comment: "would expect quadratic here as well" why would you expect that? It is linear.

Comment: Please don't invalidate answers by changing your question.

Comment: @KellyBundy that's a valid point. sorry for that. what would be the correct way around this, posting a new question and linking?

Comment: Perhaps. Although if my answer's suggestion wasn't enough to give you the expected results (could depend on the stability of your computer), I can update my answer with complete code that I think will work for you. In any case, I'll roll back the edit now. Sorry if that also undoes typo fixes or so, feel free to put those back in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your lambda ignores its argument `n` and instead always produce the same **constant**-size input. Produce input of size `n` instead.

(A note: originally the question had 8 functions and 7 of them were judged "constant time". It was edited to a larger constant and then got other judgements. I guess your computer's speed is somewhat unstable, as the constant input should still lead to constant runtimes and thus "constant time" judgements. In any case, the input-generating function should be fixed like I said.)

Given that it's two-dimensional, you could for example produce n lists of size 1, one list of size n, or sqrt(n) lists of size sqrt(n). Presumably n lists of size 1 is what you want if your goal is to demonstrate that `sum(arr, [])` is bad. For example:

```
lambda n: [[i] for i in range(n)]
```

A full program:

```
import big_o
from itertools import chain

def chained(arr):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(arr))

def merge_extend(arr):
    output = []
    for l in arr:
        output.extend(l)
    return output

def merge_w_sum(arr): 
    return sum(arr,[])

def merge_bucket(bucket):
    return [number for n in bucket for number in n]

funcs = [
    (chained, 10**5),
    (merge_extend, 10**5),
    (merge_w_sum, 10**4),
    (merge_bucket, 10**5),
]

for _ in range(3):
    for func, max_n in funcs:
        complexity = big_o.big_o(
            func,
            lambda n: [[0]] * n,
            max_n=max_n,
            n_timings=10,
        )[0]
        print(
            f'{func.__name__:13}',
            complexity
        )
    print()
```

Sample results:

```
chained       Linear: time = 8.2E-05 + 5.8E-08*n (sec)
merge_extend  Linear: time = -4.2E-06 + 8.4E-08*n (sec)
merge_w_sum   Quadratic: time = 0.00013 + 2.4E-09*n^2 (sec)
merge_bucket  Linear: time = 0.00046 + 8E-08*n (sec)

chained       Logarithmic: time = -0.0075 + 0.0014*log(n) (sec)
merge_extend  Linear: time = -2E-05 + 8.5E-08*n (sec)
merge_w_sum   Quadratic: time = 0.00011 + 2.4E-09*n^2 (sec)
merge_bucket  Linear: time = -4.2E-05 + 2.6E-07*n (sec)

chained       Linear: time = -1.8E-05 + 1.6E-07*n (sec)
merge_extend  Logarithmic: time = -0.01 + 0.0019*log(n) (sec)
merge_w_sum   Quadratic: time = 8.3E-05 + 2.4E-09*n^2 (sec)
merge_bucket  Linear: time = 7.1E-05 + 8.3E-08*n (sec)
```

You can see it gets it right most of the time, but still sometimes thinks logarithmic instead of linear. On a more stable system it might work better. Larger `max_n` values should help, too, but I tried and then `big_o` crashed with some [known](https://github.com/pberkes/big_O/issues/31) internal error.

Also note that I used different `max_n` values for the different functions. It's no good to use the same for all. If you use the same for all, then if it's large, a quadratic time solution takes unbearably long, and if it's small, a linear time solution takes so little time that `big_o` has trouble differentiating it from logarithmic or linearithmic. There doesn't seem to be a medium value that's good for all. Ideally, `big_o` would automatically adjust `max_n` appropriately, but I don't think it supports that.

Comment: Frankly, I was aware that the produced lists of lists are always of the given length (50) with the sub-lists being of length 9900 (now updated), but I didn't think that was an issue (basically, I was just assuming that you can give the *big_o.big_o* function a particular, big enough input, and this is enough for it to perform the complexity evaluation - but now that I've read the module's code more thoroughly, I realized this can't be the case and that a variable *n* is certainly essential as an input to the data generator function

Comment: @Irina Yeah, big_o requests inputs for n from 100 to 100000 (by default, can be changed) and analyzes how much the runtime grows. If you ignore that n and give it constant data, it doesn't see growth. Doesn't matter if it's constantly small like with your original 50 or constantly large like with your new 9900.

Comment: @Irina I added a full program, results and some remarks about them. What results do you get with this program on your computer?

Comment: wow, thanks! I got linear for *chain* and *merge_extend*, as well as quadratic for *merge_w_sum* every iteration and every run; for the list comprehension one I sometimes get 1x linear and 2x linearithmic or vice versa, and sometimes 3x linear.

Answer (score 3):

First it's important to understand that [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is about estimating the asymptotic growth of functions.
I.e. how they "behave" when input size grows to infinity.

E.g. if an algorithm is said to run in **O(n^2)**, it means (roughly) that when the
input size (**n**) grows to infinity, the execution time will be bound by a constant multiplied by **n^2** (for a more accurate definition see the link above).

Therefore the "real" big-O has nothing to do with concrete time measurements (in particular because we cannot measure infinite input) - at least in the theoretical sense.

Libraries like pypi/big-O **try** to estimate how the processing time grows when input size grows.
But it is only an **estimation** and depends heavily on the properties of the time function, and size of input you actually give it.

In your case, it seems like you gave it too small input.
This resulted in very short execution times that caused the estimation method to fail.
You can try to increase the input size significantly.

---

**Update:** the last paragraph (regarding the reason the input is too small) was a guess that turned out to be wrong - see [@KellyBundy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72520627/python-big-o-seems-to-return-completely-incorrect-results-what-am-i-doing-wron/72524393#72524393) above.

Comment: So it's not because their lambdas ignore their argument `n` and return the *same* data all the time?

Comment: I don't know. I am not familiar with this library. I tried to give some general background to suggest what might be the problem. I could have been wrong in my specific suggestion aty the end, but I believe most of my answer still holds.

Comment: Most of that "background" is common knowledge and I disagree that "real" big-O has "nothing" to do with concrete time measurements. In practice it does. That final paragraph finally does address the question, and I do believe it's wrong. I think the issue isn't that the generated inputs are small, it's that they're *constant*. No surprise to get the judgement "constant time" when it actually does take constant time due to constant inputs. The only slightly surprising judgement is the "cubic" one, but that's explained by seeing how tiny the cubic part was (probably misinterpreted noise).

Comment: @KellyBundy no, because *big_o.datagen.integers(n, min, max)* returns a list of random integers between min and max, and then *[big_o.datagen.integers(n, min, max) for n in range(x)]* would correspondingly return a list of *x* lists of *n* random integers between *min* and *max* each. (which I had tested anyway before posting the question, because I had also had that suspicion for a moment)

Comment: @wohlstad this has definitely been helpful, many thanks - I have changed the randomly generated test datasets now to list of 50 lists with 9900 numbers each (see the updated question) - and now the performance evaluation is extremely slow and returns "too high" complexity for 50% of the functions tested, reasonable complexity for about 30% of fctns tested, and too low compexity for the rest (see the updated question for the most prominent examples)

Comment: @Irina Huh? What do you mean, "no"? Your description is wrong and so is this answer.

Comment: @KellyBundy I stand corrected about the specific case. Added an update with reference to your answer (and upvoted it as well). BTW - the "background" might be trivial for you, but some others might find it relevant.

Comment: Yeah ok, maybe. I still disagree with the "has nothing to do with", though. If that were true, `big_o` wouldn't be able to mostly correctly determine the complexities.

Comment: @KellyBundy I meant "has nothing to do with" in the theoretical sense. As you probably know, you cannot really infer the big-O complexity from any set of measurements. You can only "guess" based on some samples from the time function but it is very different than analyzing big-O in the "mathematical" way. I thought it is a good point to clarify for those who are new to the subject. I agree in practice big-O differences affects running time (otherwise this whole field of computer-science had very little impact in real life).